# how to save a file using fwprintf in utf-8 format

Tags: visual-c++, utf-8

Friends,

I am a beginner in c++ and I am using vc 6.0 to write a file in utf-8 encoding.

I am using fwprintf function for this. but the file is coming in ANSI coding. can anybody tell me how to save a file in utf-8 using fwprintf().

Here is my code,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wchar.h"
#include "windows.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen ("abc.txt","w");
    fwprintf(file, L"This is my utf-8 encoded file");
    fclose(file);
    WinExec("\"C:\\Program Files\\EditPlus 3\\editplus.exe\abc.txt", SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VC 6 is too old. It's ancient. If you can use some modern version (VS2005, 2008, 2010, 2013) then, by all means, use it.

Comment: Dear friends,
Thank you for your valuable effort to help me to get this solved. 
Still I am not able to solve it, since I am using C style program to solve it and I am in vc6.0.

well I got to know about the function, _wfopen() but this also seems to not to create a file in utf-8 mode. 

Atleast once if you can cofirm me that there is no api in vc6 to do this. I will try to rewrite my entire code in vc++ 6.0.

Waiting for your replies thank you.

Comment: First code example from Remy Lebeau is using `C`, so it is what you are after. Answer from Remy is so complete that no reply could add any value to it. You should accept that answer, and use that code.

Comment: And to confirm: VC6 does not support UTF-8 out of the box. You need additional code, which could be yours, or it could come from some other library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler allows it you can replace `"w"` with `"w,ccs=UTF-8"` in `fopen` call.

Comment: This won't work on VC6; fopen with stream encoding support for UNICODE, UTF-8 and UTF16-LE didn't appear until VC 2005.

Comment: Which is almost 10 years old. Why would a newly minted programmer use an old compiler anyway?

Comment: I wonder this myself. [You can get the newest VC tool set from MSDN for free](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx), with more OS compatibility and standards compliance. I'd recommend the Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop package to write console programs. VC6 dates back to 1998, and is not much use for anything from Windows 2000/XP onward.

Comment: i used _wfopen() but still not able to do it.
Here is the link to msdn reference, can any one give me a piece of code to work in c and not in cpp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246392%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: @user3587879 sorry, I haven't noticed that you are using VC6. My answer is no good for VC6.

Comment: Dear Remy,

I tried the first code that is c based. Its saving the file in ANSI mode as shown in editplus. Is there any other way to save in c in vc 6.0

Comment: @user3587879 you replied to my answer instead to Remy's, so he will not be notified about your reply. I can just say that your example string does not have a single character out of the ASCII range, and so it is impossible to verify that the code works. Use some exotic characters, like Cyrillic, Hebrew, Arabic, or some such. In VS2002 an later you could use `\U` prefix to hardcode a Unicode character, but if I remember correctly this prefix does not work in VC6. So, I don't know how to help you...

Comment: Thank you dear ... I checked its working ... and sorry since I am new to the forum, I misplaced my comment.

still actually for my mis-placing of comment I got the answer, 
so thank you very much.
Thanks to all friends, especially remy.

Answer (score 3):

`fopen()` does not support encodings in VC6, so you will have to manage the encoding manually in code instead, eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wchar.h"
#include "windows.h"

bool writeUtf8StrToFile(FILE *file, const wchar_t *str)
{
    if (!file) return false;
    int wlen = lstrlenW(str);
    if (wlen == 0) return true;
    int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, str, wlen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8len == 0) return false;
    char *utf8 = (char*) malloc(utf8len);
    if (!utf8) return false;
    utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, str, wlen, utf8, utf8len, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8len == 0) return false;
    fwrite(utf8, 1, utf8len, file);
    free(utf8);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen ("abc.txt", "wb");
    if (file)
    {
        writeUtf8StrToFile(file, L"This is my utf-8 encoded file");
        fclose(file);
        WinExec("\"C:\\Program Files\\EditPlus 3\\editplus.exe\" abc.txt", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively (since you did say you are using C++ and not C, which the above code is):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wchar.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool writeUtf8StrToFile(std::ofstream &file, const std::wstring &str)
{
{
    if (!file.is_open()) return false;
    if (str.empty()) return true;
    int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8len == 0) return false;
    std::string utf8(utf8len, '\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), &utf8[0], utf8len, NULL, NULL);
    file << utf8;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ofstream file("abc.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        writeUtf8StrToFile(file, L"This is my utf-8 encoded file");
        file.close();
        WinExec("\"C:\\Program Files\\EditPlus 3\\editplus.exe\" abc.txt", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use the UTF-8 library from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14637/UTF-With-C-in-a-Portable-Way), eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wchar.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include "utf8.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ofstream file("abc.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::wstring utf16str = L"This is my utf-8 encoded file";
        std::string utf8str;
        utf8::utf16to8(utf16str.begin(), utf16str.end(), std::back_inserter(utf8str));
        file << utf8str;
        file.close();
        WinExec("\"C:\\Program Files\\EditPlus 3\\editplus.exe\" abc.txt", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use the UTF-8 stream convertor from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams), eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wchar.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "stxutif.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wofstream fs("abc.txt", std::ios::out);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::locale utf8_locale(std::locale(), new utf8cvt<false>);
        file.imbue(utf8_locale); 
        file << L"This is my utf-8 encoded file";
        file.close();
        WinExec("\"C:\\Program Files\\EditPlus 3\\editplus.exe\" abc.txt", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```